# AmazonSES: отправка писем

Tags: email, amazon, php

Друзья, очень срочно нужно отправить 1 письмо на 500 адресов.

**AmazonSES + DKIM** готовы этим заняться.

**Возможность AmazonSES:** 5 писем в секунду.

Как с помощью **PHP + cron** отправить их? Проблема именно в расчете.

Думаю, отправил одно письмо - ждешь usleep(200), потом еще одно и так пока все не уйдут.

---

Также, в будущем нужно будет отправить одно письмо на 140 000 адресов, тоже бы не плохо узнать как правильно это сделать. Но в данный момент приоритет на первом вопросе.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ничего не нужно рассчитывать, Amazon не настолько туп чтобы не взять это на себя.

Просто сливайте все что нужно в метод `sendMail`, дальше Amazon сам разберется.